# Issue as chokepoint for current sprint

Tags: jira

Is there a way to give a certain issue a "chokepoint" characteristic e.g.: I can promote the issues to a further position in the workflow only if ALL issues have caught up to that chokepoint.

More specifically: Following workflow: `A -> B -> C`
The transition to C should only be possible if and only if all issues are in state B.

**Why do I need it:** For example we have a two week sprint and everything is implemented. In order to deploy to the pre-production-server we would need to run all tests so the issue "running all tests" or "pass all tests" would be a "chokepoint" since every issue which comes afterwards can only be worked on when this one is done.